# Multi Transpose Paste into Single Column Excel

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I have a set of columns in Excel that I would like to restructure into one long list. The idea is to take all instances in row 1 (ie. `A1, B1, C1, D1` etc.) and get them into a running list in a new column in a new sheet. That is easy enough, the problem is that I have several rows that I would like to reformat following each other. What I would like is the following:

```
Row 1: A1, B1, C1
Row 2: A2, B2, C2
Row 3: A3, B3, C3
etc..
```

to end up in a long list in a single column like:

```
Column 1: A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2, A3, B3, C3.
```

I'm dealing with some 300 rows of entries here, and about 8 columns per entry so a by hand copy-paste-transpose solution would be my last resort. I have a feeling there might be a smart macro solution to this, but Im not well versed in macros.

Comment: What have you tried? Try recording a macro, try something, post some code here and then you are more likely to get help than if it looks as if you haven't even had a crack yourself.

Comment: as i said - i have no ideas how to use macros. so i dont know even if that is a thing for. cant really start with something you dont know even if it is an answer, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with recording a macro. Use keyboard as much as you can to make dynamic code (at least selecting cells and ranges). It would be something like:

1. Select cell A1 in both sheets. Go to first sheet (with rows)
2. Start recording macro
3. Press Ctrl+Shift+Arrow_Right
4. Ctrl+C
5. Change sheet
6. Paste transposed in selected cell
7. Change sheet
8. Press Arrow_Down
9. Press Ctrl+Shift+Right_Arrow
10. Ctrl+C
11. Change sheet
12. Press Ctrl+Arrow_Down
13. Press Arrow_Down
14. Paste transposed in selected cell
15. GoTo point 7

After few rows you can stop recording, check generated code, learn something about loops in VBA and finish your code. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for actually helping me! good input - worked perfectly